# Can you name this town?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language, geography

1. I am a town in the state of Karnataka in India.
2. The first two syllables of my name means 'man, hero or a person' in the ancient Indian language of Sanskrit.
3. The next four syllables translate to 'lion' and 'King' in the official language of the state.
4. The last two syllables mean 'town'.
5. I am named after an ex-king of that province.

Who am I?

Comment: This seems like trivia and not a puzzle...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like trivia and not a puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

> [Narasimharajapura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimharajapura).

1. This is a town in the state of Karnataka.
2. > "[Nara](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=nara&script=&direction=SE&link=yes)" means man, hero, or person in Sanskrit.
3. > "[Simha](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=lion+in+kannada)" and "[raja](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=king+in+kannada)" mean "lion" and "king" respectively in [Kannada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada), the official and administrative language of the state of Karnataka.
4. > "[Pura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pur_(Vedic)#Pur_and_Pura)" is a suffix meaning city or settlement, and the oldest Sanskrit word for city.
5. [Apparently](http://www.onefivenine.com/india/villages/Chikmagalur/Narasimharajapura/Narasimharajapura) the town got its name after [this fellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanteerava_Narasimharaja_Wadiyar), a prince, visited it in 1915.

Comment: Correct answer. Well done! In your point 3 above, you need to change the word, 'Sinha' to 'simha'. Cheers!

Comment: @CleoGP Google told me it was 'sinha', but OK :-)

Comment: Sinha is a Sanskrit term originates in the Indian subcontinent, common in India, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh and Pakistan, covering south Asia. It comes from the Sanskrit word "Siṃha" ('ng' sound), which means lion. In Kannada, the local language of Karnataka, the word for lion is simha, which is derived from the word, sinha I suppose. You did great work. Congrats!